# Mongoose, enforce changes to schema after mongoose.model('core_user').schema = new mongoose.schema(...)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using the Express-Restify-Mongoose library to generate all of my endpoints for a REST api.

I am storing my schemas in a collection named 'core_schema.' Each time the server starts all records within that collection are grabbed using a find() method. This provides an array of all available collections with defined schemas.

```
db.on('open', function(){
  findDocs('core_schema', {}, function(docs){
    var tempString = JSON.stringify(docs);
    var tempObj = JSON.parse(tempString);

    for (var i = 0; i < tempObj.length; i++) {
      var temp_schema = new mongoose.Schema(tempObj[i].schema_data, { collection: tempObj[i].collection_name });
      var temp_model = mongoose.model(tempObj[i].collection_name, temp_schema);

      restify.serve(router, temp_model, { plural: false, name: tempObj[i].collection_name, preCreate: setDateTimes });
    }
  });
});
```

I would like to be able to make changes to the schema to enforce new POST rules, but when I try to use a test example like:

```
mongoose.model('core_user').schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    update_count:       { type: "String", required: false },
    created_date:       { type: "String", required: false },
    created_by:         { type: "String", required: false },
    updated_date:       { type: "String", required: false },
    updated_by:         { type: "String", required: false },
    first_name:         { type: "String", required: true },
    last_name:          { type: "String", required: true },
    username:           { type: "String", required: true },
    password:           { type: "String", required: true },
    somethingElse:      { type: "String", required: true }
}, {collection: 'core_user'})
```

Where 'somethingElse' is the new field I am trying to enforce it does not enforce it. What am I doing wrong? Is there no way to update the model to use the new schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update a Mongoose schema, you'll need to use the [Schema.add](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-add) method. You can update the schema for a model using the code below:

```
mongoose.model('core_user').schema.add({ somethingElse: {
  type: 'String',
  required: true
}});
```

Comment: Wow thats awesome, works like a charm, is there an easy way to alter the schema and also remove a field if need be?